# C# WPF Property type another class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, properties

```
public class StudentNames : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   string firstname
   string surname

   public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstname;
        }
        set
        {
            if (firstname != value)
            {
                firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
       }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get
        {
            return surname
        }
        set
        {
            if (surname != value)
            {
                surname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            }
       }
    }
 }

public class StudentDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string address StudentNames sn

    public string SN
    {
        get
        {
            return sn;
        }
        set
        {
            if (sn != value)
            {
                sn = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SN");
            }
       }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return address;
        }
        set
        {
            if (address != value)
            {
                address = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Address");
            }
      }
    }
 }
```

elsewhere I have the logic:

```
StudentDetails sd = new StudentDetails()
sd.StudentNames.FirstName = "John"//this part gives me a runtime error
```

It compiles but I get a runtime error :

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: `sn` is a `string` or an instance of `StudentNames`? It is not clear. Please format and correct your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your public constructor should look like this:

```
public StudentDetails() {
  StudentNames = new StudentNames();
}
```

You got error, because you haven't set object reference to StudentNames field.
Then you can do

```
var sd = new StudentDetails():
sd.StudentNames.FirstName = "John"
```

Also, next time you should better add full code of class.

Comment: ... Next time the OP should do a search first, which yields the well known question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it. Then the OP should follow one suggestion that states: use a Debugger ... sorry for being a bit cynical.